# Mini-Game Totals Not Adding Up

Tags: c

Long story short, I'm currently learning C programming and today I'm trying to build a mini game that calculates a players total based on the results of a dice they rolled.

I have the program functional in the sense that it prompts the user for input and compares their rolls to make sure they have entered the correct info.

The problem I'm having is that the total, which is displayed at the end of the program, does not seem to be adding up. Regardless of the results I enter, the total value is always 1.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int R1, R2, R3;
    int totalScore = 0;

    puts("Welcome to CRAZY dice game!");

    puts("Enter Roll 1 Value: ");
    scanf("%d", &R1);

    while (R1 < 1 || R1 > 6) {
        puts("Value is outside accepted input, try again: ");
        scanf("%d", &R1);
    }

    puts("Enter Roll 2 Value: ");
    scanf("%d", &R2);

    while (R2 < 1 || R2 > 6) {
        puts("Value is outside accepted input, try again: ");
        scanf("%d", &R2);
    }

    puts("Enter Roll 3 Value: ");
    scanf("%d", &R3);

    while (R3 < 1 || R3 > 6) {
        puts("Value is outside accepted input, try again: ");
        scanf("%d", &R3);

    }

    if (R1 == 1 || 2) {
        totalScore = totalScore + 1;
    }
    else if (R1 == 3 || 4) {
        totalScore = totalScore + 2;
    }
    else if (R1 == 5 || 6) {
        totalScore = totalScore + 3;
    }


    if (R2 < R1) {

        switch (R2){

            case '1':
            case '2':
                totalScore = totalScore + 1;

            case '3':
            case '4':
                totalScore = totalScore + 2;

            case '5':
            case '6':
                totalScore = totalScore + 3;
        }
    }


    else {
        totalScore = totalScore;
    }


    if (R3 < R2) {

        switch (R3){

            case '1':
            case '2':
                totalScore = totalScore + 2;

            case '3':
            case '4':
                totalScore = totalScore + 4;

            case '5':
            case '6':
                totalScore = totalScore + 6;
        }
    }

    else if (R3 < R1) {

        switch (R3){

            case '1':
            case '2':
                totalScore = totalScore + 1;

            case '3':
            case '4':
                totalScore = totalScore + 2;

            case '5':
            case '6':
                totalScore = totalScore + 3;

        }
    }

    printf("Total Score is: %d", totalScore);
}
```

Comment: could you also add some scenarios with actual inputs and actual output against expected outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problems:

1. These:

   ```
   if (R1 == 1 || 2)
   else if (R1 == 3 || 4)
   else if (R1 == 5 || 6)
   ```

   doesn't do what you expect. They should be

   ```
   if (R1 == 1 || R1 == 2)
   else if (R1 == 3 || R1 == 4)
   else if (R1 == 5 || R1 == 6)
   ```
2. This:

   ```
   switch (R2){

       case '1':
       case '2':
           totalScore = totalScore + 1;

       case '3':
       case '4':
           totalScore = totalScore + 2;

       case '5':
       case '6':
           totalScore = totalScore + 3;
   }
   ```

   should be

   ```
   switch (R2){

       /* Remove the '' as R2 is not a character, but an integer */
       /* Add breaks so that execution does not slip into subsequent cases */
       case 1:
       case 2:
           totalScore = totalScore + 1;
           break;

       case 3:
       case 4:
           totalScore = totalScore + 2;
           break;        

       case 5:
       case 6:
           totalScore = totalScore + 3
           break;
   }
   ```

   and the same goes for other `switch-case`s.

## Suggestions:

1. This is a lot of repeated code:

   ```
   puts("Enter Roll 1 Value: ");
   scanf("%d", &R1);

   while (R1 < 1 || R1 > 6) {
       puts("Value is outside accepted input, try again: ");
       scanf("%d", &R1);
   }

   puts("Enter Roll 2 Value: ");
   scanf("%d", &R2);

   while (R2 < 1 || R2 > 6) {
       puts("Value is outside accepted input, try again: ");
       scanf("%d", &R2);
   }

   puts("Enter Roll 3 Value: ");
   scanf("%d", &R3);

   while (R3 < 1 || R3 > 6) {
       puts("Value is outside accepted input, try again: ");
       scanf("%d", &R3);
   }
   ```

   I suggest making a function and and returning a value:

   ```
   int getVal()
   {
       static int counter = 1;
       int temp;

       puts("Enter Roll %d Value: ", counter);
       scanf("%d", &temp);

       while (temp < 1 || temp > 6) {
           puts("Value is outside accepted input, try again: ");
           scanf("%d", &temp);
       }

       counter++;

       return temp;
   }
   ```

   and call the function from `main` using:

   ```
   R1 = getVal();
   R2 = getVal();
   R3 = getVal();
   ```

   or use an array in `main` like:

   ```
   int R[3];
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   int R1, R2, R3;
   ```

   so that you can use:

   ```
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
       R[i] = getVal();
   }
   ```
2. This:

   ```
   else {
       totalScore = totalScore;
   }
   ```

   doesn't do anything. Remove it.

Comment: I could make more suggestions if you edit your question to include what your program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
if (R1 == 1 || 2)
```

It needs to be written as:

```
if (R1 == 1 || R1 == 2)
```

and likewise for the other cases.

Two further problems in your `switch`s - you seem to be missing `break` statements, and you have written your `case` labels as if they were characters, e.g.

```
    case '1':
    case '2':
        totalScore = totalScore + 2;
```

should be:

```
    case 1:
    case 2:
        totalScore = totalScore + 2;
        break;
```

(unless you are actually intending to "fall through" to the next case label ?).

Comment: So when using the OR statement with a variable, I need to classify the variable on both sides?

I can't believe I forgot the breaks... That's what I get for trying to do this at 2 a.m. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelRice "_So when using the OR statement with a variable, I need to classify the variable on both sides?_" -- Yes.